# Using spread syntax with function Arguments object

Tags: javascript, arrays, arguments, spread-syntax

I know one has to be very careful with the function [Arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)

But are there any known downsides (optimization/performance issues) to using the spread syntax with the Arguments object? Or is this totally okay?

I want to create an array from an unknown amount of arguments passed to a function:

```
function Numbers(){
    this.numbers = [...arguments];
}
```

**[A fiddle can be found here](https://jsfiddle.net/wilt/93c0rof1/)**

It looks quite neat, and in the MDN page about the Arguments object is even suggested that I can use spread syntax for this:

> As you can do with any Array-like object, you can use ES2015's `Array.from()` method or [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to convert `arguments` to a real Array

But I still would like see if others have another opinion on this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can also use [rest parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters):

```
function Numbers(...numbers){
    this.numbers = numbers;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Using a spread does the same thing cleaner in ES2015

```
this.numbers = [...arguments];
```

Just remember that this won't work in arrow functions *(no `arguments`)*, and you're good. Rest arguments and Array.from are other options that are fine as well.

The old-fashioned ES5 is:

```
this.numbers = [].slice.call(arguments);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to use spread notation (it's not an operator) with `arguments`. Or at least, it's as fine as it ever is to use `arguments`. In ES2015 and above (e.g., if you have spread notation), there's very limited call to use `arguments`.

And indeed, there's no need in your example: Use rest arguments:

```
function Numbers(...args){
    this.numbers = args;
}
```

In that example, `args` is an array. A true array.

Comment: Nice, didn't know I could do that too :)

Answer (score 0):

One reason people say not to use the arguments object is because it looks like an array but its not:

> The arguments object is not an Array. It is similar to an Array, but does not have any Array properties except length. For example, it does not have the pop method. However it can be converted to a real Array:

You're good to go here because, like Array.from() the spread operator makes a new copy

Comment: That's *one* reason. There's also a performance impact in loose mode, and arrow functions don't have their own `arguments` object.